# ReactiveCocoa nested map

Tags: ios, dictionary, reactive-cocoa, racsignal

```
[[[[[self.textfield.rac_textSignal throttle:0.5] flattenMap:^RACStream *(id value) {
    //call api
    return [API signal];
}] flattenMap:^RACStream *(NSArray *result) {
    result = [result.rac_sequence take:150].array;
    //result is json array
    return result;
}] map:^id (NSArray *result) {
    return [result.rac_sequence map:^id (JSON *r) {
        //handle json item
        return item;
    }].array;
}] subscribeNext:^(NSArray *result) {
     //reload ui
} error:^(NSError *error) {
} completed:^{
}];
```

How to avoid the nested map in the signal sequence?
It is a better way to handle this?

Comment: What is the intent of the inner `map`? You have an array, you convert it into a sequence, map it into another identical sequence, and then turn it back into an array...?

Comment: i have to convert an array of Class JSON into another array of Class B  


         
    `Array <JSON> <-- but in here i need to convert into sequence to map and back to array again  --> Array<B>`

Wonder is it a elegant way to do this